# Send variables between action calls

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 actions:

```
add_action('init', 'activate');
add_action('wp_footer', 'code');
```

`activate` needs to set cookies and generate some html code out of it in a variable called `$html`

`code` then simply needs to output that code at the `wp_footer` along with other html code.
I noticed that `$html` is empty at `code` even though init has been called first and the variable should be filled with the right code. calling `global $html` didn't help, the variable is still empty.
How can I change it so `$html` has the right contents when `code` is called and is not empty?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to define the variable $html globally, e.g. `global $html;`